# How to create "lock" (stop updating of cells) in Excel?

Tags: excel, function, locking

My question is pretty simple, but one to which I can't really find a solution myself. I use Excel quite frequently, but rarely the fancy stuff. Anyway, to the point:

How do I create a dropmenu that will lock certain cells, rows or columns?
(by lock I mean unable to change via hand and stops updating itself).

Example: **A1** = 5, **B1** = A1 * 100, **C1** = A1 * 100

Can I "lock" the B1-cell, so that changing A1 will have no effect on B1 (Will remain at value 500), but will normally affect C1-cell (will update and calculate new value)?

I would preferably want to be able to "unlock" the cell as well, instead of simply making function into value.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, this is not possible

Answer (score 1):

You would need to programmatically store the formula from B1 somewhere as text, then convert B1 to Value (use copy-paste value or similar). To unlock the cell copy the formula back to the cell.

Comment: So... can this be done with a simple "lock / unlock" dropmenu or checkbox?
Since I know how to do this by hand, but I'd really love to do it quickly with one button / trigger, which I don't know how to code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just change the "Workbook Calculation" setting (in Excel 2007, it's under Office Button > Excel Options > Formulas) from Automatic to Manual? What'll happen then is that B1 (or any other formula) won't update unless you hit F9 (or use the equivalent command) to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! But that isn't what I'm looking for, I should've explained it a bit better, sorry.

Say that I want ONLY B1-cell not to update. But other cells normally

Answer (score -2):

copy value of B1 and paste value only, record this sequence as macro and assign a button. Run this macro when required